# Hitchhiker killer movie

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember seeing this movie as a child in the 80s so it's probably a 70's movie.

A guy picks up a hitchhiker and ends up murdering him/her (can't remember), to dispense of the body he puts her in a wheel-chair, puts a large hat and sunglasses on her to disguise the fact she is a asleep and goes to a movie theatre. In the movie theatre when dark he swaps the victim out of the chair and wheels himself out wearing the hat and glasses.

Comment: Wow, that sounds clever (and devious)! But I have no idea what the movie is.

Comment: At first it sounded like [The Hitcher (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091209/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2) until you started talking about the wheel chair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I got it: The Australian thriller [End Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_Play) from 1976 about two brothers, one of them wheelchair-bound, suspected in the murders of blonde hitchhikers. One hitchhiker (who wore a large hat) is found in a cinema and the wheelchair is used to dispose of her. You can briefly see the killer in a blonde wig and sunglasses setting the body up in [this trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp1X0DRVJeY) around 1:14. There's also a [longer trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kx90i8aGMbc) available.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like, The Freeway Killer? Movie made about the true story of a guy from California (William Bonin) who picked up hitchhikers...young men and boys, and raped/murdered them..late 70's into the 80's. Hope this helps!

Comment: I looked this movie up - looks like it was made in 2010, the film I'm after was around in the 80s